# Exporting DB table to Excel in MAMP phpMyAdmin causes Error 6

Tags: phpmyadmin

When trying to export a DB table to Excel using phpMyAdmin in MAMP on my localhost, I'm getting the following error:

This webpage is not found
No webpage was found for the web address: ../localhost/phpMyAdmin/export.php
Error 6 (net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND): The file or directory could not be found.

CSV export works fine but I want to export as Excel?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

John